# Upload a file with ExpressJS on AppFog

Tags: node.js, express

I updated my app on AppFog and my app is able to upload files on different folders, it works in local but it doesn't work on AppFog...

```
var file_tmp = file.path;
var file_name = file.name;
var file_type = file.type;
var file = './public/files/'+folder+'/'+file_name;
fs.rename(file_tmp, file, function(err){
    if( err ) console.log(err);
});
```

I don't get an error but I'm not able to see the file in the browser, I've might made a mistake, I don't know exactly if the path is correct.

**Edit #1**

new.jade (creation)

```
  form.admin(action='/creations/save', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
    div
      label(for='title') Title
      input(type='text', name='title', placeholder='Title...')
    div
      label(for='thumbnail') Thumbnail
      input(type='file', name='thumbnail')
    div
      label(for='moodboard') Moodboard
      input(type='file', name='moodboard')
    div
      label(for='description') Description
      textarea(name='content', name='description', cols='30', rows='5', placeholder='Description')
    div
      label(for='location') Location
      input(type='text', name='location', placeholder='Location...')
    div
      label(for='date') Date
      input(type='date', name='date')
    input(type='submit', value='Save')
    input(type='reset', value='Cancel')
```

app.js

```
app.post('/creations/save', restrictedArea, creations.save);
```

creations_controller.js

```
exports.save = function(req, res) {
    saveFile(req.files.thumbnail, 'thumbnails');
    saveFile(req.files.moodboard, 'moodboards');
    global.db.Creation.create({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        location: req.body.location,
        date: req.body.date,
        thumbnail: req.files.thumbnail.name,
        moodboard: req.files.moodboard.name
    }).success( function(creation){
        res.redirect('/glovebox');
    });
}
```

saveFile function in creations_controller.js:

```
var saveFile = function(file, folder){
    var file_tmp = file.path;
    var file_name = file.name;
    var file_type = file.type;
    var file = './public/files/'+folder+'/'+file_name;
    fs.rename(file_tmp, file, function(err){
        if( err ) console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Here you are just renaming the files where is the upload part.

Comment: This function is able to upload the file and it works in local.

Comment: Please show the whole request handler for app.post statement

Comment: I've edited my post, see above "Edit #1".